# Mirror screens until GDM starts

Tags: boot, nvidia, multiple-monitors, gdm

I have two monitors, and my larger primary monitor takes a long time to "wake" when it first receives an input. Due to bad luck, my graphics card outputs to my secondary monitor at boot, but once the boot finishes and `gdm` starts up my settings come into effect and my main screen turns on.

Because of the long wake time, this last step takes annoyingly long. It could be avoided if I could just mirror the two screens (the Ubuntu splash and so on) during boot, since then my primary monitor would receive a first input much earlier.

**Is there a standard way (perhaps a linux `cmdline` option) to do this?** I'm running Ubuntu 19.10.

(I can't just swap the input cables, because the monitors use different input standards.)

Comment: You haven't provided your release details, but I like `sddm` because it shows the login details on all monitors (I often turn one off)

Comment: Sorry, updated! I'm fine once my desktop manager starts, though. I'd just like *some* output to appear earlier. I really don't actually care what (e.g. blank purple would be fine).